# SPN for HttpClient Impersonation

Tags: httpclient, kerberos, impersonation, spnego

I am calling a web service with C# using HttpClient impersonation to an existing java WebLogic web service using spnego.sourceforge.net.   Let's call the windows machine "machinename.forest.company.com" and the url "https://weblogicnode.forest.company.com:7772/form/index.jsp".  The WebLogic service is using a keytab file krb5.keytab with user "serviceid@forest.company.com".

I am getting the error "Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Checksum failed)" when spengo tries to decode the Kerberos token.

I understand that using UseDefaultCredentials with HttpClient generates the Kerberos token under the hood, but I do not know what SPN it is using.

I have set the SPNs with:

```
setspn -S HTTP/machinename.forest.company.com FOREST\SERVICEID
setspn -S HTTPS/machinename.forest.company.com FOREST\SERVICEID
```

Is there a different SPN I should use?  ("HOST"? port number?)

Does the client need to know the keytab file?  Can I still do impersonation if I generate the token with Kerberos.NET and the keytab file?

The client code is:

```
var identity = (WindowsIdentity)System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal.Current.Identity; //asp.net
//var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(); //console
using (identity.Impersonate())
{
    using (System.Threading.ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow())
    {
        AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false);
        HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = true,
            AllowAutoRedirect = true,
        };
        var cred = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials.GetCredential(uri, "Negotiate");
        using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
            foreach (var headerItem in headerItems)
            {
                message.Headers.Add(headerItem.Key, headerItem.Value);
            }
            var response = client.SendAsync(message).Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I needed to explicitly set the SPN on the client.

```
if (!System.Net.AuthenticationManager.CustomTargetNameDictionary.ContainsKey(uri.AbsoluteUri))
{
    System.Net.AuthenticationManager.CustomTargetNameDictionary.Add(uri.AbsoluteUri, "HTTPS/weblogicnode.forest.company.com");
}
```

Here I am using the WebLogic Node instead of the machine name, so I'm setting that with:

```
setspn -S HTTP/weblogicnode.forest.company.com FOREST\SERVICEID
```